# Combining geom_point() legends

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I combine the two legends into one "Species" legend in the code below?

```
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = "red", size = Species))
```

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(aes(color =Species))

Comment: @Puriney Thanks, but I need to use a single color and show the difference via size/shape attribute

Comment: I wonder if you wanna move `color = "red"` outside of `aes()`. `ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(aes(size = Species), color = "red")`.

Comment: @jazzurro Didn't see your comment earlier. As I commented to the answer below, this is exactly what I wanted - thanks!

Comment: @Manojit No worries. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove "colour" out of the aesthetics. This seems to be what you are after.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Species), colour = "red")
```

[image]

If you want to keep colour as an aesthetic, then
you can manually override the colour in the size legend guide

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Species, colour = "red")) +
  guides(colour = FALSE, 
         size=(guide_legend(override.aes = 
                              list(colour = "red"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Keeping`color`out of`aes()`is exactly what I wanted - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer visualizing the data in this way if you would like to add the information of the sample size per class.

```
cat_table <- table(iris$Species)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
geom_point(aes(color =Species)) + 
scale_color_manual(breaks=names(cat_table), labels=paste(names(cat_table), ':', cat_table), values=rainbow(n=length(cat_table)))
```

[image]

Comment: This method works great for this simple example, but my actual dataset has a large number of categories, and adding too many colors tend to clutter it up. That is why I was looking to use one color and different shape/size.